# Why is my fetchRequest returning nil?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

My fetch request is returning nil from an entity that I think I've successfully put data into and after hours and hours of debugging, I haven't been able to figure it out. (Disclaimer: I've looked at the countless threads here on SO that talk about fetch requests and unwrapping options but every one I found is about how to deal with the unwrapping error. I'm asking for help figuring out why my fetch request isn't returning a record when I believe it should.)

In the view controller where I'm going to display the data, I have this in viewWillAppear:

```
class LiftLogTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var liftEvents = [LiftEvent]() 

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LiftEvent")

    do {
      if let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [LiftEvent] {
        liftEvents = results  <---- nil error happening here

        }
    }  catch {
      fatalError("Error fetching data!")
    }
  }
```

But I believe there's a record in there because in AppDelegate.addData() I've done this:

```
    // create a lift event in LiftEvent
    let liftEvent = LiftEvent(entity: liftEventEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let dateStr = "05-27-2016"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let date: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)!

    liftEvent.date = date
    liftEvent.liftEventUid = 1
    liftEvent.liftUid = 1
    liftEvent.formulaUid = 1
    liftEvent.maxAmount = 250

    print("Added lift ID: \(liftEvent.liftEventUid) lift ID: \(liftEvent.liftUid) weight: \(liftEvent.maxAmount) formula: \(liftEvent.formulaUid) ")

    saveContext()

  }

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
      do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nserror = error as NSError
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        abort()
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm learning CoreData so at this point I have to assume there's something basic I'm just missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Vadian, the managedObjectContext is a lazy variable (see next comment)...

Comment: `  lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
      //Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
      let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
      var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
      managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
      return managedObjectContext
  }()'

Comment: Yes, but it's declared in the scope of `AppDelegate`, that means, it's not visible anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard Core Data template you need to assign a value to the `managedObjectContext` property in the `LiftLogTableViewController` class.

For example in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}
```

However the recommended way is to pass the context via the segue.

Comment: It works! Thanks!  I had it initialized lazily only in AppDelegate but not in the LiftLogTableViewController but I just redeclared it as you saw in my code above and that was the problem. I used your best practice tip to pass it via the segue and that fixed it.

Comment: "redeclare" is a confusing term. You declared a property `managedObjectContext` of class `NSManagedObjectContext` which is not necessarily the instance declared in `AppDelegate`.